# Lodash remove to remove an object from the array based on an id property

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am looking at the lodash documentation for `remove()` and I am not sure how to use it.

Say I have an array of Friends,

`[{ friend_id: 3, friend_name: 'Jim' }, { friend_id: 14, friend_name: 'Selma' }]`

How do you remove `friend_id: 14` from the array of Friends?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use filter.

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];

var oneAndThree = _.filter(myArray, function(x) { return x !== 2; });

console.log(allButThisOne); // Should contain 1 and 3.
```

Edited: For your specific code, use this:

```
friends = _.filter(friends, function (f) { return f.friend_id !== 14; });
```

Comment: ah.  how do you know whether to use filter or remove?  sorry if that's a really basic question..

Comment: It's just personal preference.  For me, remove is stupid because it changes your array, PLUS is returns an array with the removed values, where filter just returns the filtered values.

Comment: oh okay.  do you think this makes sense then?  I am using lodash for ngrx/store like this:  `return assign({}, state, {
        items: filter(state.items, {id: action.payload.id})
      });`

Answer (score 23):

[Remove](https://lodash.com/docs#remove) expects a predicate function. See this example:

```js
var friends = [{ friend_id: 3, friend_name: 'Jim' }, { friend_id: 14, friend_name: 'Selma' }];

_.remove(friends, friend => friend.friend_id === 14);

console.log(friends); // prints [{"friend_id":3,"friend_name":"Jim"}]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this

```
list.splice(_.findKey(this.list, function(e) {
    return e.id === 12;
}), 1);
```